# use output variables from another stage in a different stage

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have the next code snippets:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  name: A
  displayName: "Run tf ${{ parameters.action }}"
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '***-${{ parameters.env }}' 
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      if [ ${{ parameters.action }} = "plan" ]; then
          echo "Running terraform plan..."
          timeout -s SIGINT 58m terraform plan out=terraform.plan
          changes=$(terraform show -no-color terraform.plan | grep -E "No changes.")
          echo "Checking for Changes variable [$changes]"
          if [ -n "$changes" ]; then
            echo "No changes detected. Exiting without further actions."
            echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=PlanChanges; isOutput=true]'notdetected
          else
            echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=PlanChanges; isOutput=true]'changesdetected
          fi
      else
          echo "Running terraform apply..."
          timeout -s SIGINT 58m terraform apply input=false auto-approve
      fi
    addSpnToEnvironment: true
    workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}'
```

These tasks are part of a template called script.yml and it is used in another template called stages.yml following the next structure in the next comment:

```
parameters:
- name: workingDirectory
  type: string
- name: environments
  type: object
  default:
  - dev
  - qa


stages:
- ${{ each env in parameters.environments }}:
    - stage: Plan_${{ env }}
      condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
      jobs:
        - job: Plan
          steps:
          - template: script.yml
            parameters:
              env: ${{ env }}
              action: plan
              workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}'

    - stage: Apply_${{ env }}
      dependsOn:
        - Plan_${{ env }}
      jobs: 
      - deployment: 
        displayName: Deploy
        environment: ${{ env }}
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:            
              - template: script.yml
                parameters:
                  env: ${{ env }}
                  action: apply
                  workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}'
```

Now, I have isOutput=true option for (echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=PlanChanges; isOutput=true]'notdetected), I need to consume this output variable in my Apply stage which is a different one.
I need to set a condition based on this output for the Apply Stage to be skipped/to run only the variable output is "changesdetected"... but I tried first to consume that variable to see if works.

I have tried referencing this variable in the stages.yml:
adding variables:
varPlan:  $[ stageDependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.Plan.outputs['PlanOverview.PlanChanges'] ]
or
varPlan:  $[ stageDependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.outputs['Plan.PlanOverview.PlanChanges'] ]   when I run the script echo $(varPlan) not showing the output of variable.

According to: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops&branch=pr-en-us-1603#job-to-job-dependencies-across-stages:~:text=Dependency%20syntax%20overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops&branch=pr-en-us-1603#job-to-job-dependencies-across-stages:%7E:text=Dependency%20syntax%20overview)

how to reference that variable output to my condition in the apply stage?

Tried like these:
varPlan: $[ stageDependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.Plan.outputs['AzureCLI@2.PlanChanges'] ]

varPlan: $[ stageDependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.Plan.outputs['A.PlanChanges'] ]

varPlan:  $[ dependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.outputs['Plan.AzureCLI@2.PlanChanges'] ]

varPlan:   $[ stageDependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.outputs['Plan.A.PlanChanges'] ]

varPlan:  $[ stageDependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.Plan.A.outputs['PlanChanges'] ]

varPlan:  $[ stageDependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.Plan.outputs['PlanOverview.PlanChanges'] ]

varPlan: $[ stageDependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.PlanOverview.outputs['PlanChanges'] ]

varPlan: $[ stageDependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.Plan.outputs['PlanOverview.PlanChanges'] ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the stage-level of all the "**`Apply_xxx`**" stages, you can set the condition like as below.

```yaml
- ${{ each env in parameters.environments }}:
  - stage: Plan_${{ env }}
    . . .
  
  - stage: Apply_${{ env }}
    dependsOn: Plan_${{ env }}
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(stageDependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.outputs['Plan.A.PlanChanges'], 'changesdetected'))
```

With this condition, the "**`Apply_xxx`**" stages will run when the value of output variable "**`PlanChanges`**" is "**`changesdetected`**".

---

In addition, another important thing you need to know is that based on the current definition in your main YAML (**`stages.yml`**), all the stages will run in a single line in sequence based on their order of defining in the YAML file. So, they will look like as below in a pipeline run.

[image]

In this situation, a stage will be skipped if any of the previous stages is not succeeded. For example, on above image, in the expected result, the "**`Apply_prod`**" stage should run but it was skipped due to the previous "**`Apply_qa`**" stage was skipped.

For your case, the ideal results should be:

- "**`Plan_dev`**" and "**`Apply_dev`**" are in a separate line, and "**`Apply_dev`**" only depends on "**`Plan_dev`**".
- "**`Plan_qa`**" and "**`Apply_qa`**" are in a separate line, and "**`Apply_qa`**" only depends on "**`Plan_qa`**".
- "**`Plan_prod`**" and "**`Apply_prod`**" are in a separate line, and "**`Apply_prod`**" only depends on "**`Plan_prod`**".

To reach this, you can update the main YAML (**`stages.yml`**) like as below:

1. Add a "**`main`**" stage as the parent node of all the separate lines. In this "**`main`**" stage, you can let it do nothing. So, it will be always succeeded.
2. Set the "**`Plan_xxx`**" stage to depend on the "**`main`**" stage.
3. Set the "**`Apply_xxx`**" stage to depend on the "**`Plan_xxx`**" stage.

```yaml
stages:
- stage: main
  jobs:
  - job: main
    steps:
    - checkout: none

- ${{ each env in parameters.environments }}:
  - stage: Plan_${{ env }}
    dependsOn: main
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
    jobs:
    . . .
  
  - stage: Apply_${{ env }}
    dependsOn: Plan_${{ env }}
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(stageDependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.outputs['Plan.A.PlanChanges'], 'changesdetected'))
    jobs:
    . . .
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

- **For the question in your first reply blow:**

  If I did not misnderstand your demands, when the value of output variable (**`PlanChanges`**) generated from '**`Plan_${{ env }}`**' stage is '**`changesdetected`**', then the corresponding '**`Apply_${{ env }}`**' stage should run and not skip, and when the output value is '**`notdetected`**',  the '**`Apply_${{ env }}`**' stage should skip.

  So, if '**`Plan_prod`**' stage outputs '**`changesdetected`**', the '**`Apply_prod`**' stage should run. On the first pipeline image I posted above, the '**`Plan_prod`**' stage was outputting '**`changesdetected`**', the '**`Apply_prod`**' stage should not skip.
- **For the question in your second reply below:**

  You seem have wrong syntax when use the **`setvariable`** command to set the output variable using Bash.

  Change the command line like as the following:

  ```bash
  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PlanChanges;isoutput=true]notdetected"
  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PlanChanges;isoutput=true]changesdetected"
  ```

---

**EDIT_2:**

Below I will share you with a sample that I attempted on my side. In this sample, I set the "**`Apply_qa`**" stage will be skipped based on the condition below.

```yaml
condition: and(succeeded(), eq(stageDependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.outputs['Plan.A.PlanChanges'], 'changesdetected'))
```

You can reference this sample to check and update the code in your YAML files.

- The main YAML file: **`azure-pipelines.yml`**

```yaml
parameters:
- name: workingDirectory
  type: string
- name: environments
  type: object
  default:
  - dev
  - qa
  - prod

stages:
- stage: main
  jobs:
  - job: main
    steps:
    - checkout: none

- ${{ each env in parameters.environments }}:
  - stage: Plan_${{ env }}
    dependsOn: main
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
    jobs:
    - job: Plan
      steps:
      - template: script.yml
        parameters:
          env: ${{ env }}
          action: plan
          workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}'
  
  - stage: Apply_${{ env }}
    dependsOn: Plan_${{ env }}
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(stageDependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.outputs['Plan.A.PlanChanges'], 'changesdetected'))
    jobs:
    - deployment: Deploy
      environment: ${{ env }}
      variables:
      # The variable can be used by the steps (include script.yml) within this job. 
        varPlanChanges: $[ stageDependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.Plan.outputs['A.PlanChanges'] ]
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - template: script.yml
              parameters:
                env: ${{ env }}
                action: apply
                workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}'
```

- The template YAML file: **`script.yml`**

```yaml
steps:
- task: Bash@3
  name: A
  displayName: 'Set Output'
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      if [ ${{ parameters.action }} = "plan" ]; then
        echo "The action is ${{ parameters.action }}."
        echo "The environment is ${{ parameters.env }}."
        if [ ${{ parameters.env }} = "qa" ]; then
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PlanChanges;isoutput=true]notdetected"
        else
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PlanChanges;isoutput=true]changesdetected"
        fi
      else
        echo "The action is not plan. It is ${{ parameters.action }}."
        echo "The environment is ${{ parameters.env }}."
      fi

- ${{ if eq(parameters.action, 'plan') }}:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Variables for plan action'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        echo "env = ${{ parameters.env }}"
        echo "action = ${{ parameters.action }}"
        echo "workingDirectory = ${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}"
        echo "PlanChanges = $(A.PlanChanges)"

- ${{ if eq(parameters.action, 'apply') }}:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Variables for apply action'
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        echo "env = ${{ parameters.env }}"
        echo "action = ${{ parameters.action }}"
        echo "workingDirectory = ${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}"
        echo "varPlanChanges = $(varPlanChanges)"
```

- The result of running the pipeline, see the second image I posted above.

---

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your time! I will try this too but why in the first pipeline image that you showed the apply_prod should be considered not skipped while plan_prod has no changes?  because my condition is set dependency only when checking for changes in Plan_{{env}}?  or I miss something in this logic. trying your approaches, really appreciate your time!

Comment: I tried as you suggested first running this condition: condition: and(succeeded(), eq(stageDependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.outputs['Plan.A.PlanChanges'], 'changesdetected')) and my job apply remain skipped every time and it makes me think the output reference is not working. 

in my if condition I used:  echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=PlanChanges; isOutput=true]'changesdetected    having the flag isOutput=true that the variable to be exported outside stage and job.

Comment: @be9inn3r, For the questions in your above two replies, I have updated my above answer with more information (see **EDIT**). check and try it.

Comment: I have tried your initial method and my problem still persists, not discovered yet why. I will analyze and trying your changes too.

Comment: The problem is that having - template: script.yml
            parameters:
              env: ${{ env }}
              action: plan
              workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}' — in script.yml I am running the if condition which set the output variable planChanges depending on that condition. The problems is that I cannot consume this variable in another Stage even if I use stageDependencies condition for apply to be skipped if output variable from plan has the value “nochanges”. Thinking why? Because it is run in a template and cannot reference correctly?

Comment: Because after that if statement which decide the output variable all this represent a task, the next task(script) is created as to show the output variable (with echo) and is displaying the value but note that next one task(script) is run immediately once the above which is done, so in same stage and job.  My script.yml contains more tasks including this one with statement if and the next one with echo script.  I trying to be clear for you to understand my problem

Comment: I was looking for my initial Apply stage because I was thought a problem could be the usage of Deployment which can make some  problems for reference as I found in other topics discussed and I tried to use above it, as first a simple Job called Applying which run only a simple echo and to set a condition for it to run only when the stageDependencies output variable contains “changestdetected” value from if statement from Plan stage, plan job, scrip.yml . Not working

Comment: I have tried to change my output var declaration as you told: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PlanChanges;isoutput=true]notdetected" (including no space between variable and isOutput), with “” exactly as you recommend but this is not working and the next echo task to check that variable output is saying is empty and variable cannot found. This was the reason I’m using the command like I showed initially including that space and it working to show the variable but not exported? Because that space? I ve found in documentation that is needed to be deleted, I deleted it and same, not working

Comment: @be9inn3r, I have updated my above answer with a sample that I attempted on my side (see **EDIT_2**), and the sample can work well. You can reference this sample to check and update the code in your YAML files.

Comment: works. great, Bright! thank you so much! Now, after your sample, I understand better how the variable is passed between stages and jobs... 

In my output variable it was also wrong set the variable:  echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=PlanChanges; isOutput=true]'changesdetected   <- NOT WORKING as expected, not working the option isoutput=true.  But using:
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=planChanges;isoutput=true]changesdetected" is working as expected and it passed between stages/jobs.
As I read in ms documentation, there should be no spaces between variable and option isoutput.

Comment: also, thank you for the example with dependsOn Main which is great and is more suitable for my case.

Comment: Hi, I am back. Related to your first and second images. If I keep my initial/original pipeline sequentially, how can make it only skip the apply stage for dev if there are no changes and continue with the next environment? and not to skip the entire pipeline?

*used your method in parallel; but in sequent mode can I accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Two options for you to try:

---

**Option 1**:

When using `isOutput=true`, you have to redefine the variable in the job or stage that it needs to be used in.

The syntax to reference a stage dependency is as follows:

`$[ stageDependencies.StageName.JobName.outputs['StepName.VariableName'] ]`

I have refactored your yaml file a bit to flatten it into one script for simplicity, and also renamed some fields. Here is a full example that may work for you:

```
parameters:
- name: workingDirectory
  type: string
  
- name: environments
  type: object
  default:
  - dev
  - qa
  - prod 

stages:
- ${{ each env in parameters.environments }}:
    - stage: Plan_${{ env }}
      condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
      jobs:
        - job: Plan
          steps:
          - task: AzureCLI@2
            name: PlanScript
            displayName: "Run tf plan"
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '***-${{ parameters.env }}' 
              scriptType: 'bash'
              scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
              inlineScript: |
                echo "Running terraform plan..."
                timeout -s SIGINT 58m tfmake azure plan out=terraform.plan
                changes=$(terraform show -no-color terraform.plan | grep -E "No changes.")
                echo "Checking for Changes variable [$changes]"
                if [ -n "$changes" ]; then
                  echo "No changes detected. Exiting without further actions."
                  echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=planChanges; isOutput=true]'notdetected
                else
                  echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=planChanges; isOutput=true]'changesdetected
                fi
              addSpnToEnvironment: true
              workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}'

          - script: |
              terraform show terraform.plan 
              echo $(planChanges)
            workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}'
            displayName: "Plan overview"
            name: PlanOverview    

    - stage: Apply_${{ env }}
      dependsOn:
        - Plan_${{ env }}
      jobs: 
      - deployment: 
        displayName: Deploy
        environment: ${{ env }}
        variables:
          varPlan: $[ stageDependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.Plan.outputs['PlanScript.planChanges'] ]
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:            
              - task: AzureCLI@2
                displayName: "Run tf apply"
                inputs:
                  azureSubscription: '***-${{ parameters.env }}' 
                  scriptType: 'bash'
                  scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
                  inlineScript: |
                    if [ "$(varPlan)" = "changesdetected" ]; then
                      echo "Running terraform apply..."
                      timeout -s SIGINT 58m tfmake apply input=false auto-approve
                    else
                      echo "Plan changes is: $(varPlan)"" 
                    fi
                  addSpnToEnvironment: true
                  workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}'
```

---

**Option 2**:

You may be able to simplify your yaml a hole lot by having all your scripts run in a single job, that way you don't need to worry about parsing variables between stages/jobs.

```
parameters:
- name: workingDirectory
  type: string

- name: environments
  type: object
  default:
  - dev
  - qa
  - prod 

stages:
- ${{ each env in parameters.environments }}:
  - stage: Plan_and_Apply_${{ env }}
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
    jobs: 
    - deployment: 
      displayName: Deploy
      environment: ${{ env }}
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:            
            - task: AzureCLI@2
              displayName: "Run tf plan"
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: '***-${{ parameters.env }}' 
                scriptType: 'bash'
                scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
                inlineScript: |
                  echo "Running terraform plan..."
                  timeout -s SIGINT 58m tfmake azure plan out=terraform.plan

                  changes=$(terraform show -no-color terraform.plan | grep -E "No changes.")
                  echo "Checking for Changes variable [$changes]"

                  if [ -n "$changes" ]; then
                    echo "No changes detected. Exiting without further actions."
                  else               
                    echo "Running terraform apply..."
                    timeout -s SIGINT 58m tfmake apply input=false auto-approve
                  fi
                addSpnToEnvironment: true
                workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}'
```

Comment: Being back with feedback for option 1… this one being the one preferred in my case. I was thinking if that I am using the script.yml is not read the output variable because of this script cannot be referenced well… testing you option.

Comment: Initially, I wanted only to test the value of $(varPlan) to see exactly if the varPlan: $[ stageDependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.Plan.outputs['PlanScript.planChanges'] ] is well referenced. In that case, to set a condition for apply stage based on stageDependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.Plan.outputs['PlanScript.planChanges'] ]  .

Comment: But in my case, I am using that template instead of using directly the tasks in the template with job stages declaration and maybe this is a reason why the varPlan is not read/shown.